# Meteor - Adding a favourite/like user accounts

Tags: meteor

I have a page where I display a list users. I would like the current user "is_teacher" to be able to 'like' the individual users in the list. The likes are only visible to the teacher. I thought the best way to do this would be to add a `likes: String` in the collection and store the students_Id but my code must be way off because its not working. Can someone checkout what I've done I let me know where I'm going wrong.

Path: `Schemas.js`

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
        likes: {
            type: [String],
            optional: true
        }
    });
```

Path: `sudentList.html`

```
<template name="studentList">

    {{#each student}}

    {{#if like}}
    <button class="like">Unlike</button>
    {{else}}
    <button class="like">Like</button>
    {{/if}}

    {{/each}}

</template>
```

Path: `studentList.js`

```
Template.studentList.helpers({
  like: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({likes: this._id});
  }
});

Template.studentList.events({
  'click #like':function(event,template) {
    var student = this._id;
    Meteor.users.update({likes: student}, {$set:{likes:!student}});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer because I can't comment.

It's really unclear what's going on because your code is a bit of a mess, and we need a bit more information than "it's not working" to diagnose the issue.

Some obvious points are:

- Your button has a class (`.`), but your event is bound to an id (`#`)
- Your update function is odd. (To say the least!)

  - `likes` is an array, so you wouldn't use `$set` with a string
  - `student` is a string, so `!student` is just `false`
  - Presumably since your schema is for user profiles, your find/update operations should go for `profile.likes` not just `likes`

This is just a guess, but I think your event should be more like:

```
Template.studentList.events({
  'click #like':function(event,template) {
    var student = this._id;
    var teacher = Meteor.userId();
    Meteor.users.update({_id: student}, {$push:{"profile.likes": teacher}});
  }
});
```

But it's hard to say because I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.